# Javascript Currency Format

Tags: javascript

Hello all I am in need of some help here. I am in no way a javascript programmer but I have pieced together some code to do what I need it to do, but I am having trouble with the currency formatting of what I have. In the code below myForm.man_quan.value doesn't need the $ but does need commas separating the thousands, and myForm.man_price.value needs the $, commas, and .00 if the price is without cents.

Basically I need to be able to add the $ and , and .00 to what I have.

```
function runTotal(myForm) {
var form_field1 = Number(myForm.man_quan.value);
var form_field2 = Number(myForm.man_price.value);
myForm.man_total.value = form_field1.toFixed(0) * form_field2.toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your looking for parseInt() http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp
since it's currency, you might want to use parseFloat http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

so it sould be somthing like:

```
function runTotal(myForm) {
    var form_field1 = parseFloat(myForm.man_quan.value);
    var form_field2 = parseFloat(myForm.man_price.value);
    myForm.man_total.value = form_field1.toFixed(0) * form_field2.toFixed(2);
}
```

Re-adding the , for the thousands, might be more tricky. but you can reform the var to string with toString() and adding the $ sign like so.

```
var output = "$"+myForm.man_total.value.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function runTotal(myForm) {
var form_field1 = formatmoney(myForm.man_quan.value);
var form_field2 = formatmoney(myForm.man_price.value);
myForm.man_total.value = form_field1.toFixed(0) * form_field2.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, it actually didn't do anything but break the calculation process.

Answer (score 0):

Replace or remove unnecessary symbol like $ and comma

```
form_field1 = myForm.man_quan.value.replace(',', '.');
form_field2 = myForm.man_price.value.replace('$', '');
myForm.man_total.value = form_field1 * form_field2;
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work either. I'm still not getting the $ and commas.

Answer (score 0):

very simple function in JavaScript called **toLocaleString**

> Note: Data type should be integer

```
function numTocurrency(num)
{
   return parseInt(num).toLocaleString();
}
```

Comment: Would the output of `toLocaleString` be formatted as currency?

Comment: Int would cause the cents part of the value to be lost.

Comment: what do you mean by cent part?

Comment: you mean the decimal number like(float, double)?